# Flutter, firestore order by two fields

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, geofirestore

I'm trying to make two sliders in my app, when they are move users from Firestore should be filtered and loaded to listview, I'm getting this error:

> Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(invalid_query, FIRInvalidArgumentException, Invalid query. You have a where filter with an inequality (lessThan, lessThanOrEqual, greaterThan, or greaterThanOrEqual) on field 'age' and so you must also use 'age' as your first queryOrderedBy field, but your first queryOrderedBy is currently on field 'position.geohash' instead.)

I'm using GeoFlutterFire and firestore, that's code:

```
  Future<Stream<List<DocumentSnapshot>>> getUsersInRadiusAndAge(double radius,
      double minAge, double maxAge) async {
      Query q = _firestore.collection('users').where('age', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: minAge, isLessThanOrEqualTo: maxAge);

      Position userLocation = await Geolocator().getCurrentPosition();

      GeoFirePoint center = geo.point(
          latitude: userLocation.latitude, longitude: userLocation.longitude);

      return geo.collection(collectionRef: q)
          .within(center: center, radius: radius, field: 'position');

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

This query is wrong:

```
  Query q = _firestore.collection('users').where('age', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: minAge, isLessThanOrEqualTo: maxAge);
```

You should do the following:

```
Query q = _firestore.collection('users').where('age', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: minAge).where('age', isLessThanOrEqualTo: maxAge);
```

This will return the documents that have age >= minAge and age <= maxAge

Comment: are you sure the error is on this line? Do you have a field called "position.geohash"?

Comment: Yes I have, 'position.geohash' and searching by distance works normally, but when im trying to make query to search by distance and age it is not working

Comment: any other solutions?